"End of the world" type TV series
I remember a TV show that was aired around 10 years ago. Trying to remember what it was called.

The world froze over
Humanity lived in these domes ontop of the ice
Domes were connected via bullet train
Some 'domes' were at war with others, if you broke laws they threw you out onto the ice, people were poor
Resources were scarce, but (obviously) there was a dictator who lived off of everyone else

A movie similar to this in ways is Snowpiercer, but this was a TV show.

Got a nationality for this TV series? English speaking?

Could be Grand Star

"Grand Star", formerly known as "Ice Corp.", is a futuristic, action-adventure series based on the saga by French novelist Georges J. Arnaud. In the latter part of the 21st century, there is a cataclysmic explosion on the moon, which was being used as a nuclear waste dump and the earth is turned into a frozen mass of ice. Billions died but a few thousands have managed to rebuild their lives in railway stations like "Grand Star", where they must learn to survive in the frozen landscape home to strange near humans of unknown origin who can withstand the cold and the "renewer" who profess the return of the Sun.




